# Displaying multiple database query results, one at a time with some delay between each DB

Tags: php, sql-server

I am a beginner PHP coder, so if my code looks way crazy, apologies up front.

I have been tasked with (trying to) write a program that will loop through a list of databases (and servers too but I will figure that part out later), send each database the same query, then display the results for few seconds, then the next query ect... I have this close in that I can display all of the results the way I want, but it is all one after the other on the same page and you would need user interaction to scroll down to see each db result. I am trying to do this in a way that once started, will just loop through the databases one at a time and display it without user interaction (It will be on a TV for users to refer to throughout the day). Another problem is that I am stuck using 5.3 update24 I think (we have other programs that use it and wont run on anything newer (that's another project for another day).

I tried to use `session_start()` with `session_write_close()` or `session_destroy()` or `Sesson_reset()` at the end of the loop but this just re-initializes the same results, as opposed to for example draw the table with results of database1, wait 3 seconds, clear the screen, then display the next database results in the loop.

I'm close to giving up since I could find no one else that has done this or at least no one that asked the same question that I could find. My code is below, the query was anonymized..

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>stuff older than 3 days</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.php"/>
        </head>
        <body>

<?php

/*
* Comments here
*/
$serverName = "192.168.0.90";
$databaseName = "";
$dbUsername = "xxdbuserxx";
$dbUserpass = "xxdbpassxx";
$db_Name_Array = parse_ini_file("dbname.ini");
$db_Srv_Array = parse_ini_file("srvname.ini");
$k=0;
$countq=0;

//Loop through each database listed in the ini file
foreach($db_Name_Array as $section=>$values){
        //$databaseName=$section


            $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $dbUsername, "PWD" => $dbUserpass, "Database" => $section);        
            $link = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
            //read the array and print
            $sql = "SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6 from Table;

            //stmt1 is solely for retrieving the number of rows, unfortunately it cant be retrieved from the normal stmt query.

            $stmt1 = sqlsrv_query( $link, $sql, array(), array('Scrollable' => 'buffered'));

            //display the number of results in the case that there are too many to see on the screen
            $countq=sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt1);
            // now do the same query but for displaying them to the screen
            $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $link, $sql);
            echo "<h2>$values  ----- ( # of sessions older then 3 days: $countq )</h2>";
            echo"<table class='table1'>";
            //set the Header

        echo"<tr class='qtop1'><td>field1</td><td>field2</td><td>Field3</td><td>Field4</td><td>Field5</td><td>Field6</td></tr>\n";

        //loop through the results changing color of every other row to make it easier to read

        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
            if ( isset($k) and $k==0){  
            echo"<tr class='d0'><td>{$row['Field1']}</td><td>{$row['Field2']}</td><td>{$row['Field3']}</td><td>{$row['Field4']}</td><td>{$row['Field5']}</td><td>{$row['Field6']}</td></tr>\n";
            $k=1;
            }
            else{
            echo"<tr class='d1'><td>{$row['Field1']}</td><td>{$row['Field2']}</td><td>{$row['Field3']}</td><td>{$row['Field4']}</td><td>{$row['Field5']}</td><td>{$row['Field6']}</td></tr>\n";
            $k=0;       
            }

        }
        echo"</table>";
        if( $stmt === false ){  
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
}

?>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code within the `<head>` section of your page.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
```

This will tell the browser to refresh/reload every 3 seconds.

Leave the session_start() on the page but remove all of the other session_*() functions.

***EDIT***

What you are wanting is pagination with auto-refresh. Looking at your code you would need to make the following changes:

```
<?php
session_start();
//--- keep track of where we are
if( !isset($_SESSION['PageCount']) )
   $_SESSION['PageCount'] = 0;
/*
* Comments here
*/
$serverName = "192.168.0.90";
$databaseName = "";
$dbUsername = "xxdbuserxx";
$dbUserpass = "xxdbpassxx";
$db_Name_Array = parse_ini_file("dbname.ini");
$db_Srv_Array = parse_ini_file("srvname.ini");
$k=0;
$countq=0;

$itemsPerPage = 2; //--- how many entries to display Must be more than 1
$currentPage = $_SESSION['PageCount'];

//--- loop through number of databases that need to be displayed
for($x=0; $x<$itemsPerPage; $x++ ) {
   //--- get the info about the db and server from the respective arrays
   $dbName = $db_Name_Array[$currentPage];
   $dbSrv  = $db_Srv_Array[$currentPage];
   //--- make the connection to the database using $dbName and $dbSrv info

   //--- get the data and format it

   //--- increment the current page number
   $currentPage++;
   //--- set to zero to loop to the first entry
   if( $currentPage >= count( $db_Name_Array) ) {
        $currentPage = 0;
   }
}
//--- save the current page number to the session var
$_SESSION['PageCount'] = $currentPage;
?>
```

The above will list 2 or more entries ($itemsPerPage).

The $_SESSION['PageCount'] keeps track of which items to display.

As the code stands, the last item on the list will be the first item on the list on the next refresh.

Comment: Jeff, thank you for the response. I gave that a try and the page refreshes like it is supposed to but the same thing happens. all of the results show up in one page where you need to scroll down to see it. I tried to add a sleep 3 seconds at the end of the foreach and also after the echo"< /table>"; statement but still the same.

Comment: Another observation, I tried ob_start() with an ob_flush() or ob_end_flush() after the last echo statement but still the same thing. php/html wants to loop through all of the foreach statement before outputting any of the echo statements, even if I put the flush statements in the foreach. If I could get get the output to echo or print before each iteration of the foreach loop, that would do it.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I will try this out and let you know. Thanks again for the help.